# High Disk Read I/O in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am observing high disk read I/O in Elasticsearch nodes.

Environment

- Elasticssearch 2.3.1
- Disk SSD
- Cores - 16
- RAM - 64 GB

Segments and merging could be one of the issue. But as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#segments-and-merging) I don't see any `INFO` log stating `now throttling indexing`.

Can someone let me know what could be the problem and how can I debug this issue?

The node stats looks like below:-

```
"indices" : {
            "docs" : {
              "count" : 42096315,
              "deleted" : 16809358
            },
            "store" : {
              "size_in_bytes" : 188061514556,
              "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
            },
            "indexing" : {
              "index_total" : 4971184,
              "index_time_in_millis" : 24161898,
              "index_current" : 0,
              "index_failed" : 0,
              "delete_total" : 10317957,
              "delete_time_in_millis" : 3323977,
              "delete_current" : 0,
              "noop_update_total" : 165455,
              "is_throttled" : false,
              "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
            },
            "get" : {
              "total" : 3078536,
              "time_in_millis" : 4166218,
              "exists_total" : 3076266,
              "exists_time_in_millis" : 4165295,
              "missing_total" : 2270,
              "missing_time_in_millis" : 923,
              "current" : 0
            },
            "search" : {
              "open_contexts" : 0,
              "query_total" : 811510,
              "query_time_in_millis" : 49063191,
              "query_current" : 0,
              "fetch_total" : 55590,
              "fetch_time_in_millis" : 2561106,
              "fetch_current" : 0,
              "scroll_total" : 205,
              "scroll_time_in_millis" : 68748,
              "scroll_current" : 0
            },
            "merges" : {
              "current" : 0,
              "current_docs" : 0,
              "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
              "total" : 37047,
              "total_time_in_millis" : 29575123,
              "total_docs" : 48646732,
              "total_size_in_bytes" : 189196722890,
              "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
              "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 7243267,
              "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 186360552
            },
            "refresh" : {
              "total" : 253329,
              "total_time_in_millis" : 14111583
            },
            "flush" : {
              "total" : 824,
              "total_time_in_millis" : 197608
            },
            "warmer" : {
              "current" : 0,
              "total" : 479781,
              "total_time_in_millis" : 440805
            },
            "query_cache" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 523777408,
              "total_count" : 144964341,
              "hit_count" : 5901881,
              "miss_count" : 139062460,
              "cache_size" : 7773,
              "cache_count" : 442280,
              "evictions" : 434507
            },
            "fielddata" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
              "evictions" : 0
            },
            "segments" : {
              "count" : 263,
              "memory_in_bytes" : 273031904,
              "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 203860300,
              "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 34899016,
              "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
              "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 5229120,
              "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 29043468,
              "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
              "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes" : 527069180,
              "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 14761,
              "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 7048640
            },
            "translog" : {
              "operations" : 137655,
              "size_in_bytes" : 122949018
            },
            "request_cache" : {
              "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
              "evictions" : 0,
              "hit_count" : 0,
              "miss_count" : 0
            }
          },
          "os" : {
            "timestamp" : 1508238172920,
            "cpu_percent" : 91,
            "load_average" : 22.31,
            "mem" : {
              "total_in_bytes" : 67543134208,
              "free_in_bytes" : 912490496,
              "used_in_bytes" : 66630643712,
              "free_percent" : 1,
              "used_percent" : 99
            },
            "swap" : {
              "total_in_bytes" : 4093636608,
              "free_in_bytes" : 1753239552,
              "used_in_bytes" : 2340397056
            }
          },
          "process" : {
            "timestamp" : 1508238172920,
            "open_file_descriptors" : 915,
            "max_file_descriptors" : 65535,
            "cpu" : {
              "percent" : 2,
              "total_in_millis" : 99746040
            },
            "mem" : {
              "total_virtual_in_bytes" : 87529877504
            }
          },
          "jvm" : {
            "timestamp" : 1508238172921,
            "uptime_in_millis" : 292500150,
            "mem" : {
              "heap_used_in_bytes" : 1868708912,
              "heap_used_percent" : 35,
              "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 5255331840,
              "heap_max_in_bytes" : 5255331840,
              "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 103936064,
              "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 106307584,
              "pools" : {
                "young" : {
                  "used_in_bytes" : 153647352,
                  "max_in_bytes" : 907345920,
                  "peak_used_in_bytes" : 907345920,
                  "peak_max_in_bytes" : 907345920
                },
                "survivor" : {
                  "used_in_bytes" : 35321888,
                  "max_in_bytes" : 113377280,
                  "peak_used_in_bytes" : 113377280,
                  "peak_max_in_bytes" : 113377280
                },
                "old" : {
                  "used_in_bytes" : 1679739672,
                  "max_in_bytes" : 4234608640,
                  "peak_used_in_bytes" : 3660407304,
                  "peak_max_in_bytes" : 4234608640
                }
              }
            },
            "threads" : {
              "count" : 199,
              "peak_count" : 204
            },
            "gc" : {
              "collectors" : {
                "young" : {
                  "collection_count" : 32655,
                  "collection_time_in_millis" : 1844356
                },
                "old" : {
                  "collection_count" : 611,
                  "collection_time_in_millis" : 176197
                }
              }
            },
            "buffer_pools" : {
              "direct" : {
                "count" : 258,
                "used_in_bytes" : 269582255,
                "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 269582255
              },
              "mapped" : {
                "count" : 146,
                "used_in_bytes" : 71612833894,
                "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 71612833894
              }
            },
            "classes" : {
              "current_loaded_count" : 8483,
              "total_loaded_count" : 8499,
              "total_unloaded_count" : 16
            }
          },
          "thread_pool" : {
            "bulk" : {
              "threads" : 16,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 16,
              "completed" : 44913
            },
            "fetch_shard_started" : {
              "threads" : 1,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 9,
              "completed" : 13
            },
            "fetch_shard_store" : {
              "threads" : 0,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 0,
              "completed" : 0
            },
            "flush" : {
              "threads" : 5,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 5,
              "completed" : 9011
            },
            "force_merge" : {
              "threads" : 0,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 0,
              "completed" : 0
            },
            "generic" : {
              "threads" : 1,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 6,
              "completed" : 29268
            },
            "get" : {
              "threads" : 0,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 0,
              "completed" : 0
            },
            "index" : {
              "threads" : 16,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 16,
              "completed" : 9460079
            },
            "listener" : {
              "threads" : 8,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 8,
              "completed" : 1237173
            },
            "management" : {
              "threads" : 4,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 1,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 4,
              "completed" : 44128
            },
            "percolate" : {
              "threads" : 0,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 0,
              "completed" : 0
            },
            "refresh" : {
              "threads" : 8,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 8,
              "completed" : 253330
            },
            "search" : {
              "threads" : 25,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 25,
              "completed" : 992032
            },
            "snapshot" : {
              "threads" : 0,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 0,
              "completed" : 0
            },
            "warmer" : {
              "threads" : 5,
              "queue" : 0,
              "active" : 0,
              "rejected" : 0,
              "largest" : 5,
              "completed" : 518307
            }
          },
          "fs" : {
            "timestamp" : 1508238172922,
            "total" : {
              "total_in_bytes" : 1847237029888,
              "free_in_bytes" : 921102319616,
              "available_in_bytes" : 839458172928
            },
            "data" : [ {
              "path" : "/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0",
              "mount" : "/var (/dev/mapper/vag-var)",
              "type" : "ext4",
              "total_in_bytes" : 1847237029888,
              "free_in_bytes" : 921102319616,
              "available_in_bytes" : 839458172928,
              "spins" : "false"
            } ]
          },
          "transport" : {
            "server_open" : 140,
            "rx_count" : 7926335,
            "rx_size_in_bytes" : 15511144109,
            "tx_count" : 7667433,
            "tx_size_in_bytes" : 47171921335
          },
          "http" : {
            "current_open" : 1,
            "total_opened" : 63123
          },
          "breakers" : {
            "request" : {
              "limit_size_in_bytes" : 2102132736,
              "limit_size" : "1.9gb",
              "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
              "estimated_size" : "0b",
              "overhead" : 1.0,
              "tripped" : 0
            },
            "fielddata" : {
              "limit_size_in_bytes" : 3153199104,
              "limit_size" : "2.9gb",
              "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
              "estimated_size" : "0b",
              "overhead" : 1.03,
              "tripped" : 0
            },
            "parent" : {
              "limit_size_in_bytes" : 3678732288,
              "limit_size" : "3.4gb",
              "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
              "estimated_size" : "0b",
              "overhead" : 1.0,
              "tripped" : 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

`refresh_interval` & `translog.flush_threshold_size` are both set to their default values.

hot-threads report is as follows:- (`_nodes/hot_threads?pretty"`
)

```
Hot threads at 2017-10-17T12:45:39.517Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:

   71.6% (357.8ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Axum][[denorm][1]: Lucene Merge Thread #6011]'
     3/10 snapshots sharing following 13 elements
       org.apache.lucene.index.MultiTermsEnum.pushTop(MultiTermsEnum.java:275)
       org.apache.lucene.index.MultiTermsEnum.next(MultiTermsEnum.java:301)
       org.apache.lucene.index.FilterLeafReader$FilterTermsEnum.next(FilterLeafReader.java:195)
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.write(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:438)
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.write(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:198)
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.FieldsConsumer.merge(FieldsConsumer.java:105)
       org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:193)
       org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:95)
       org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4075)
       org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3655)
       org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:588)
       org.elasticsearch.index.engine.ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ElasticsearchConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:94)
       org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:626)
```

Comment: What is your `index.refresh_interval` and `index.translog.flush_threshold_size` on configuration.

Comment: Both are set to default value. These values are not changed.

Comment: I think, _refresh will increase your I/O. Could you change it and test?

Comment: You meant to say I should increase my `index.refresh_interval` from default 1 sec to some higher value?

Comment: yes. thats right. this will lose to you being near realtime but this will decrease resource usage.

Comment: i am facing the same problem. and can't find any answer.